# Can you iterate over the XmlAttributeOverrides collection in c#

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have to dynamically assign and change complex objects attributes at run time using the System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeOverrides

So far I have been able to do everything i needed.

My one question is how can I iterate through the collection to see what has already been added?

And if I can't interate through this collection, can I join two XmlAttributeOverrides collection to form one complete one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could create an `XmlAttributeOverridesBuilder` class, similar to `XmlAttributeOverrides`, which will give you better control over the XmlAttributes it contains. That way, you could work on `XmlAttributeOverridesBuilder` instances, combine them if necessary, and call a `GetOverrides` method when you need the actual `XmlAttributeOverrides` instance.

```
public class XmlAttributeOverridesBuilder
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, XmlAttributes>> _entries;

    public XmlAttributeOverridesBuilder()
    {
        _entries = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, XmlAttributes>>();
    }

    public void Add(Type type, XmlAttributes attributes)
    {
        Add(type, String.Empty, attributes);
    }

    public void Add(Type type, string member, XmlAttributes attributes)
    {
        Dictionary<string, XmlAttributes> typeEntries;
        if (!_entries.TryGetValue(type, out typeEntries))
        {
            typeEntries = new Dictionary<string, XmlAttributes>();
            _entries[type] = typeEntries;
        }
        typeEntries[member] = attributes;
    }

    public XmlAttributeOverrides GetOverrides()
    {
        XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        foreach(var kvpType in _entries)
        {
            foreach(var kvpMember in kvpType.Value)
            {
                overrides.Add(kvpType.Key, kvpMember.Key, kvpMember.Value);
            }
        }
        return overrides;
    }

    public XmlAttributeOverridesBuilder Combine(XmlAttributeOverridesBuilder other)
    {
        // combine logic to build a new XmlAttributeOverridesBuilder
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not conveniently, no.

You can get values for types you *expect* by using the indexer - either `yourOverrides[type]` or `yourOverrides[type, memberName]` - but to get a list of *all* the data inside would require reflection (it isn't exposed on the API).

By inspection (although this is brittle), there is a field called `types` that is a `Hashtable` (keyed by `Type`). Each object in the `Hashtable` is *itself* a `Hashtable` (keyed by member-name, with `""` for the type's own settings).

Good luck, and don't blame me if it falls in a big heap when you apply some hotfix or new .NET version...